# Set cmap to a Matplotlib PatchCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a **Patch Collection** conformed by several **polygons** (triangles).
Each of that triangle have associated an integer **value**. I would like to set a **color map** to that Patch Collection based on the different values of the triangles.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib

X = np.linspace(0,10,5)
Y = np.linspace(0,10,5)
values = [np.random.randint(0,5) for i in range(0,5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = 2   # Triangle side
patches = []

# Creating patches --> How could I insert here 'value' variable? For taking it into account in cmap.
for x,y,value in zip(X,Y,values):
    tri = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(([(x      ,       y     ),
                                       (x + s/2, y - 0.866 * s),
                                       (x - s/2, y - 0.866 * s)]),
                                    lw = 2, edgecolor='black')
    patches.append(tri)

coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, match_original = True)
ax.add_collection(coll)

ax.set_xlim(1,12)
ax.set_ylim(0,12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know how could I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This [instruction](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py) seems to translate to your case pretty well:

```
# values as numpy array
values = np.array([np.random.randint(0,5) for i in range(0,5)])

# define the norm 
norm = plt.Normalize(values.min(), values.max())
coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, cmap='viridis',
                                              norm=norm, match_original = True)

coll.set_array(values)
polys = ax.add_collection(coll)
fig.colorbar(polys)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Quang Hoang. Since values array may not be ordered, do you know if I could directly associate the color value in the triangle definition? And the last thing, could be scalar squence instead of graduated color?